# Trying to ignore a file in svn

Tags: svn, maven, svnignore

We use maven and svn. It was an mistaken checkin of target directory to SVN that cause this error. I removed target from the repository:

```
svn delete -m "removing target folder" https://svn/svn/playground/denizatak/lrms-1.5-0_release_7/target/

Committed revision 19955.
```

and add ignore property regarding target:

```
svn proplist -v
Properties on '.':
  svn:ignore : target
```

However when I try to commit the project I got this message:

```
svn commit -m "licensing latest version - without target"
svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: Directory '/project/target/.svn' containing working copy admin area is missing
```

When I check the status of the target file separetly I got this message:

```
svn stat target
svn: Directory 'target/.svn' containing working copy admin area is missing
```

The status of the project is:

```
svn st
~      target
M      some files
M      pom.xml
```

Does anyone have any suggestion about this case?

Comment: have you tried "svn update" and/or "svn clean"?

Comment: Now I tried, but I got this result from svn cleanup: svn: '/project/target' is not a working copy directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try just removing the target directory from your project folder? As a precaution you could first move it somewhere else.

Subversion might just be confused by the fact that target appears to be part of a working copy (it has a .svn subdirectory) but is neither part of the current directory in your repository (you deleted it) nor is it defined as svn:externals.

Comment: That worked! But what will happen when I compiled my project and maven creates the target file again?

Comment: As you added to svn:ignore there should be no further problem. I believe that this situation arose because you performed svn delete on the repository rather than on the working copy. At the following svn update the target folder was unmarked as belonging to your working copy, but not removed.

Answer (score 0):

you appear to have corrupted or deleted your .svn directory that contains information about the link between the repo and the local directory.

First try a 'svn clean' to try and rebuild this, possibly 'svn update' too to fetch the details from the repo. If this fails, the easiest way (and the one that gives me most confidence against things going wrong) is to checkout a new working copy, then copy your changed files (NOT the .svn directories) across to there. Then checkin.

I'm not sure about the ~ on the svn st result, it means the object was changed type (eg a file has become a directory or similar), I would have expected it to show with a D for deleted, though I imagine you've added a property to a working-copy item that's no longer part of source control - and it's this that's causing confusion. I would post your question to the [svn users mailing list](http://subversion.apache.org/mailing-lists.html) to see if this kind of workflow is something that is known as a bug.

Comment: I tried svn cleanup:
    svn cleanup ~/project
    svn: '/project/target' is not a working copy directory
I am not sure about using update. It is for updating the working copy and make it equal to repository, right? If this is the case I can not use it because I have made changes in my project and I don't want to loose them.

Comment: No, `svn update` merges the repository changes into your current working copy. this doesn't delete your changes (`svn revert` would do that). However it also pulls in missing directories and files from the repository. So if you accidently deleted a complete directory or file, svn update just "fixes" the wc.

Comment: I understand. I tried update but it returns: 'code' svn update
svn: Working copy '.' locked
svn: run 'svn cleanup' to remove locks (type 'svn help cleanup' for details)'code'

Comment: I tried the answer above and it worked. But what will happen next time when I run the project using maven and maven recreates the target?